JWT authentication keeping user session alive indefintely
I am recently implemented some authentication with auth and refresh token. I know that if the auth token expires, it will automatically fetch a new one from auth service with the refresh token. However, based on my understanding, the refresh token will eventually expiry and logs the user out of the app.
However, I don’t see many apps that will log user out after a long time and they only need to sign in once and will not logs user out unless they press the “log out” button manually). They might not be using refresh tokens as session management but I wonder How do they do it if they are using refresh tokens and what is the correct way to do it?
I can only think of few reasons:

The refresh token never expires or the expiry is very long (few years)
They are using some kind of method not to my knowledge
some kind of way to “extends” the user refresh token as long as they are active


In my understanding, refresh token works with auth token in pairs to improve user experience since frequent re-authentication is not needed. The difference between auth & refresh token are:
Auth token: Shorter expiration time (in 5 - 30 minutes, depends on setting)
Refresh token: Longer expiration time (maybe few days or in unit of months)

The mechanism of those token in general.

When the auth token expires, client can use refresh token to renew the auth token.
Server verifies the refresh token and generate a new pair of auth token and refresh token
Client updates both token in secure place for next authentication

